# Tourist visa policies in Dubai

Tags: tourist-visas, uae

I'm residing in Dubai and my tourist visa will expire by June 24, 2018. Is there any grace period in Dubai, even after the expiry?

Comment: Unless somebody says otherwise, the *general rule* is that countries take dates like that **very** seriously.  Also, a tourist visa is for tourism: unusual for a tourist to *reside*, how do they support themselves without violating visa conditions e.g. taking employment. On your next entry they will look at that and may have questions.  This is all speaking generally, Dubai may differ.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [UAE Goverment](https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/visa-fees-and-tracking), a grace period is not allowed for those on a tourist or visitor visa, only for those who are residents (added emphasis mine):

> **Overstaying your visa**
>
> If a tourist or a visitor overstays, he will be fined with AED 200 for the first day of overstay, followed by AED100 each consecutive day. This is to be paid in addition to AED 100, as service fees at the immigration offices or at the airport when exiting.
>
> In the ***case of UAE residents***, they have 30 days’ grace period after visa expiry to either amend their status and get another residence visa or leave the country. Fines do not apply during the grace period.
>
> If they overstay after the grace period, they will be fined with AED 125 for the first day and AED 25 for each subsequent day.
>
> After six months of overstaying, the resident would be fined AED 50 per day.
>
> After one year of overstaying, the resident would be fined AED 100 per day.